# Disable zoom in matplotlib 3d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

3d matplotlib plot is rotated by moving mouse while left click is pressed (elevation and azimuth) and zoomed by moving mouse while right click is pressed. I would like to disable zooming of plot.

My initial idea was to detect press and release of right mouse button.

```
def button_pressed(event):
    if event.button == 3:
        #disable interacting with plot

def button_released(event):
    if event.button == 3:
        #enable interacting with plot


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', display)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', display)
```

Any other way of achieving this would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the matplotlib 3d toolkit documentation I found a method that can help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Making data
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ys = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
zs = [15,25,35,45,55,65]

# Creating the 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plotting data
ax.plot(xs, ys, zs, color='blue')

# Disabling mouse zoom by setting it to none
ax.mouse_init(zoom_btn=None)

# Labeling axis
ax.set_xlabel("X", color="red")
ax.set_ylabel("Y", color="green")
ax.set_zlabel("Z", color="blue")

plt.show()
```

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.7.2/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L938-L957

This calls the mouse_init() method on the class of your axes. When the graph is generated I set the parameter for the zoom_btn=None. This will disable the zoom of the right click drag.

This still allows for the zoom tool to be used in the bottom of the figure to be selected, and only disables the use of the zoom on the mouse.